# Proving $\phi$ is not a homomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, solution-verification, proof-explanation

> Show that $\Phi\colon\langle\mathbb Z,+\rangle\to\langle\mathbb Z,+\rangle$ where $\Phi(n)=3n+1$ is not a homomorphism.

My work should be posted below. I want to double check that this makes sense since I am not the best at proofs. Also, my teacher said that $$\phi (1) +\phi(1) = 8$$ but I do not see how that is correct. I think it is equal to $9$ instead.

Comment: What do you think the value of $\phi(1)$ is?  Is it 4.5? :)

Comment: If you want us to validate a proof of yours, then you should state your proposed proof in the body of your question rather than as an answer. There is a proof-verification tag you can use when you do this.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my proof below. Please lead me in the right direction if anything is wrong. Thank you.:

*Proof:* Let $m,n\in\mathbb Z$. Then

$$\Phi(m+n)=(3m-1)+(3n-1)+1=3(m+n)+1$$

It follows, though, that

$$\Phi(m)+\Phi(n)=(3m+1)+(3n+1)+1=(3m+3n)+2+1=3m+3n+3$$

If $m=n=1$, then $\Phi(m+n)=\Phi(2)=7$ and $\Phi(m)+\Phi(n)=\Phi(1)+\Phi(1)=9$
. Since $\Phi(m+n)\ne\Phi(m)+\Phi(n)$, $\Phi$ is not a homomorphism. $\square$

Comment: It's fine. But you could do it simpler: a homomorphism always maps unit element to unit element, and in this case the unit element is $\;0\;$ (zero), but...

Comment: in the future you should post your attempts in the question, if you’re asking for help

Comment: Please don't post questions/answers heavily relying on images.

Comment: Also: it should be $\Phi(m)+\Phi(n)=3(m+n)+\color{red}{2}$; I don't know where the extra $1$ is coming from.

Comment: $\Phi(m) + \Phi(n) = (3m+1) + (3n+1)$. You have spuriously added $1$ to this.

Answer (score 1):

If it was a homomorphism, then we would have $7=3\cdot2+1=\phi(2)=\phi(1+1)=\phi(1)+\phi(1)=(3\cdot1+1)+(3\cdot1+1)=8$.

Answer (score 1):

An easy way to see that it is not is to note that $\phi(0)=1$. But for homomorphisms we always have $\phi(e)=e$.

Comment: Nice idea, but theoretically, we could interpret it as semigroup (homomorphism).

Comment: @user7427029 ok.  I guess I assumed we weren't doing that.  Is this type of thing done alot?

Answer (score 0):

$\phi(1) = 3(1) + 1 = 4$. Then, $\phi(1) + \phi(1) = 4 + 4 = 8$.